# REST API PATCH in Java

Tags: java, rest, api, patch

If I were to implement the accepted answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807974/in-a-java-rest-api-using-patch-vs-put-to-update-an-entity) and the [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902), would I also need to create a class whose fields include **op**, **path**, **value**, and **from**?

Comment: Unfortunately your question boils down to "somebody please please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could [edit], rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Comment: In other words: why don't you *try* yourself first? And you can always try to give a comment on either the accepted answer or the question when asking for more details.

Comment: You wouldn't *have* to, but it would probably make life easier.

Comment: I much as possible I wouldn't want to set my own standards. And I'm not asking someone to do this or that. I'm expecting an answer which is based on practices applied to the standards as far as PATCH and Java are concerned.

Comment: Thanks, @chrylis. If I would't have to, how would it probably make life not easier? Can you enlighten me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to write your own JSON Patch parser.

- Java EE 8 now supports the [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) with the [JSR 374](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=374) ([JSON-P 1.1](https://javaee.github.io/jsonp/)): [`JsonPatch`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/json/JsonPatch.html), [`JsonPatchBuilder`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/json/JsonPatchBuilder.html) and [`JsonPatch.Operation`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/json/JsonPatch.Operation.html) are the main types you are looking for.
- Spring Data REST also supports the [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902): [`PatchConverter<T>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/json/patch/PatchConverter.html), [`JsonPatchPatchConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/json/patch/JsonPatchPatchConverter.html), [`Patch`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/json/patch/Patch.html) and [`PatchOperation`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/json/patch/PatchOperation.html) are the main types.
- Alternatively, if you are use Jackson, you may consider the [`json-patch`](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-patch) library.

---

**Update:** I recently put together an [example](https://github.com/cassiomolin/http-patch-spring) on how to support *JSON Patch* and *JSON Merge Path* in Spring applications. The approach I've used is described in this [post](https://cassiomolin.com/using-http-patch-in-spring/).

Comment: Do we need to write a backend parser to do a patch update? Or is there a spring db driver which does it following the RFC?

Comment: @HIRATHAKUR I recently put together an [example](https://github.com/cassiomolin/http-patch-spring) on how to support _JSON Patch_ and _JSON Merge Path_ in Spring applications. The approach I've used is described in this [post](https://cassiomolin.com/using-http-patch-in-spring/). The idea can be adapted to be used with other frameworks, such as JAX-RS. I hope it helps.

Comment: @RomanVottner Much appreciated! I believe there's some room for improvement. But it may help others to `PATCH` in the right way :)

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @chrylis, I would rather have to create a class with **op**, **path**, **value**, and **from** being the fields.